# Flattening TypeScript types recursively leads to the "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" error

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I'm working on a TypeScript type manipulation task that involves flattening a complex structure while excluding specific types using recursion. The goal is to create a type that represents the flattened structure after excluding the Row and Column types. Unfortunately, I'm running into a problem with the "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" error. The following code illustrates the problem:

```
type Column<T> = T;
type Row<T> = T;

interface Form {
  row1: Row<{
    col1: Column<{
      field1: number;
    }>;
    col2: Column<{
      field2: string;
    }>;
  }>;
}

type ExcludeType<T> = T extends Row<infer U>
  ? ExcludeType<U>
  : T extends Column<infer U>
    ? ExcludeType<U>
    : T;

type FilteredType = ExcludeType<Form>;
```

My aim is to achieve a FilteredType that represents the flattened structure, like this:

```
/*
FilteredType is:

{
  field1: number;
  field2: string;
}
*/
```

How can I modify the `ExcludeType` type to successfully flatten the structure and avoid the "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" error?

Comment: The problem is caused by the definitions of `Row` and `Col`: https://tsplay.dev/N7Vb4w Are the definitions in your actual code these

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm afraid I won't be able to implement the solution you provided, as it would require me to modify the structure of a significant amount of data. My initial hope was to address this issue by using a generic column approach, defined as `type Column<T> = T;`, but it seems that won't suffice. Nonetheless, thank you for offering your assistance.

Comment: Method 2: https://tsplay.dev/N9VAMm (breaks for functions and Maps, Sets, etc)